# helptags doesn't generate correct tags with vim-php-manual

Tags: php, vim

I download [vim-php-manual](http://blog.planetxml.de/uploads/vim-php-manual.tgz) in this [page](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/PHP_manual_in_Vim_help_format) and unzip in `~/.vim/vim-php-manual`(**the tgz file has a tags file**). I can use `K` on some function name and see the parameter of this function. Everything is good.

But I execute `:Helptags` in Vim normal mode, it generate some wired tags in `~/.vim/vim-php-manual`.

```
/   apache-request-headers.txt  /*\/*
NOT strtr.txt   /*NOT*
estimated   ifx-getsqlca.txt    /*estimated*
```

I think Vim must generate wrong tags with wrong symbol. I open the file `~/.vim/vim-php-manual/ifx-getsqlca.txt` and `:set ft=text`. I see `estimated` being surround star sign(*), like `*estimated*`, so Vim treat it as the tags name.

Is that mean I can't execute `:Helptags` forever? Because it always generates wrong tags for `vim-php-manual`

It seems contradiction because vim will find the help file in `runtimepath` and `:Helptags` will generate tags with `runtimepath`?

Comment: The link to vim-php-manual.tar.gz is not working.  (It looks as though the server is treating PHP as an ordinary file.)  Can you give an alternative download?

Comment: @benjifisher I have updated the link of plugin zip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is odd that one of the files I get when I expand `vim-php-manual.tgz` is `vim-php-manual.tgz`.

When I expand the archive, I get a bunch of `*.txt` files, a `tags` file, and the odd file I just mentioned.  No subdirectories, nothing else.  So all you have to do is create a directory, expand the archive into it, and adjust the `'tags'` option in vim.  (Use a `FileType` autocommand or put it in `.../after/ftplugin/php.vim` if you want the setting only when you are editing PHP.)

I think the idea is to use the `tags` file that comes bundled with the archive, not to generate it from the help files using vim.  If you need to regenerate the tags file, then follow the instructions on the page where you found the archive.

The `:Helptags` function (part of the pathogen plugin) only parses files with the extension `.txt` that are in a directory `doc/` somewhere under `'runtimepath'`.  If you do not want to overwrite the `tags` file when you run `:Helptags`, then call the directory where you put these files something other than `doc/`, for example `doc-php/` or `vim-php-manual/`.

I just did that, putting the files in `~/.vim/vim-php-manual/`, and ran `:Helptags` and it did not have any effect.

Comment: Oh, I add `vim-php-manual` into rtp indeed. Thanks for your patient.

Comment: I remove '~/.vim/vim-php-manual' from `runtimepath`, but `K` doesn't work at all. I add it back it will work. Is something I misunderstand?